# Send mail on login for a host

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, rhel, email

Is there any way to send a custom e-mail to custom recipients if any user tries to login or login to my system (RHEL6.7) ??

Comment: fail2ban is a brute force detection systems and can be configured to send emails on failed login attempts.

Comment: @RamanSailopal She would also like to have an email sent on _successful_ login attempts, it seems.

Comment: If a slight delay/digest mode is OK, then `logwatch` may do what you want - simply monitor the auth.log

Comment: @ivanivan little delay is Ok thanks for the response but how to use logwatch is it a package? how to setup the same? also at the same time setting this up will have any effect on the System space? just asking as it will generate logs too i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are looking for. I will list out two ways to do it.

1. `logwatch`, a log-monitoring system that can send emails reporting any ssh activity.

   ```
   sudo yum install logwatch 
   sudo cp /usr/share/logwatch/default.conf/logwatch.conf /etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf
   sudo logwatch --service sshd --range today --mailto <custom email IDs of recipients comma separated> --detail low
   ```
2. A custom shell script in the `/etc/profile.d` folder. Normally, this script will be executed each time any user logs in the system.

   You may copy the following script into ***/etc/profile.d/name_of_the_alerts_file.sh*** file. It will send an email with the text produced by the `echo`. The `whoami` will be replaced by the current user and the `hostname` by the server's name.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash 
   echo -e "
   ######################################################## 
   #  This is an alert you requested for
   #  User `whoami` logged into `hostname` at `date`
   #  
   #  
   ######################################################## 
   " | mailx -r login-alerts -s "Login-Alert on `hostname`" <recipient 1>,<recipient 2>
   ```

The second method is useful if you want to customize the message being sent in the emails.

Comment: There is Linux-Mag article describing [how to use `logwatch`](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7800/). It includes an example using it to monitor sshd activity.

Comment: @Pradeep Ravilla - Super usefull :-) heads up for the detailed solution